# Constructing list from file using generators

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to that needs to read in a matrix from a particular location in a large file.  The location of interest in the file looks like so:

```
VOLUME and BASIS-vectors are now :
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  energy-cutoff  :      500.00
  volume of cell :      478.32
      direct lattice vectors                 reciprocal lattice vectors
     7.831488362  0.000000000  0.000000000     0.127689649  0.000000000  0.000000000
     0.000000000  7.773615667  0.000000000     0.000000000  0.128640268  0.000000000
     0.000000000  0.000000000  7.856881120     0.000000000  0.000000000  0.127276967
```

I need the reciprocal lattice vectors.  There are many ways to grab those numbers, but the file is many thousands of lines long, so I can't (shouldn't) store the entire thing as a list of lines.  That restriction makes extracting the data I want a little more difficult.  This is what I have so far:

```
with open('OUTCAR','r') as read_outcar:
    for line in read_outcar:
        if 'VOLUME' in line:
            for i in range(5):  #skip to line with data
                next(read_outcar)
            buffer = line.split()
            x = [float(buffer(i+3)) for i in buffer]
            next(read_outcar)
            buffer = line.split()
            y = [float(buffer(i+3)) for i in buffer]
            next(read_outcar)
            buffer = line.split()
            z = [float(buffer(i+3)) for i in buffer]
            break
```

There are two problems here:

1.) I'm unsure if my usage of 'next' is correct/appropriate, but I don't know how else to grab lines from the file past the current line associated with the iterator

2.) My generators do not work.  The interpreter raises a type error, because I am apparently trying to concatenate str and int types.  What I want is a list of floats for each row in the the reciprocal lattice matrix.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no generators in your code, did you mean your list comprehensions?

Comment: either use while loop or add line_skip variable, set it to 2 on VOLUME

Comment: also you can use getlines

Comment: @Serge why would you want to use `getlines`?

Comment: Anyway, you are getting type errors because `i+3` tries to add a `str`, `i`, to the `int` literal `3`. You need `float(i) + 3`, but you are going to get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when you do `buffer(...)`, not sure what you were trying to do there...

Comment: or readlines - to get list which is more convenient to explore.

Comment: @Serge As the OP states, *"the file is many thousands of lines long, so I can't (shouldn't) store the entire thing as a list of lines"*, this is not the way they want to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

- `next` returns the next item of the iterator and since you split on `line` you should capture it via `line = next(read_outcat)`
- Then the buffer is a list and this is indexed via square brackets, i.e. `buffer[...]`. However since you seem to be interested in the last three elements you can just access them via `buffer[-3:]`.

Here the modified code:

```
with open('OUTCAR') as read_outcar:
    for line in read_outcar:
        if 'VOLUME' in line:
            for i in range(5):  #skip to line with data
                line = next(read_outcar)
            buffer = line.split()
            x = [float(b) for b in buffer[-3:]]
            line = next(read_outcar)
            buffer = line.split()
            y = [float(b) for b in buffer[-3:]]
            line = next(read_outcar)
            buffer = line.split()
            z = [float(b) for b in buffer[-3:]]
            print(f'x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you could do something like

```
starting_row = 5
filename = r"file.txt"
def make_me_a_generator(filename = None):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            if index >= starting_row:
                line.replace(r"\n", "")
                row = line[47:].split("  ")

                x = float(row[0])
                y = float(row[1])
                z = float(row[2])
                print(f'{x} {y} {z}')
                yield x, y, z
```

Turning your file read into a generator that you can use as needed

Answer (score 0):

```
skip_lines = 0
read_lines = 0
with open('OUTCAR') as read_outcar:
    for line in read_outcar:
        if 'VOLUME' in line:
            skip_lines = 4
            read_lines = 4
        elif skip_lines:
            skip_lines -= 1
        elif read_lines:
            read_lines -= 1

            buffer = line.split()
            x = [float(b) for b in buffer[-3:]]
            print(x)
```

or use while loop

```
    while true:
         line = next(read_outcar, '')
         if not x: break
         ...
```